# How to set Visual State Manager for template Gridview in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, gridview, windows-10, win-universal-app

I know Visual State Manager can change controls property when change size screen UWP. 
But I don't know How to use Visual State Manager for Datatemplate Gridview ? How to change property Image control, TextBlock control? please help me this situation.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="Phone">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Tablet">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<GridView x:Name="gv" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageLeague}" 
                                                Width="50"
                                               Stretch="None"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"   />


                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" 
                                                   FontSize="26" 
                                                   Foreground="Black"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                   />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to wrap the DataTemplate in a UserControl:

```
    <GridView Width="200" Height="300" x:Name="gv" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" ItemsSource="{Binding myList}">

        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Phone">
                                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="MyTextBlock.FontSize" Value="15"/>                                        
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Tablet">
                                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="MyTextBlock.FontSize" Value="25"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageLeague}" 
                                            Width="50"
                                           Stretch="None"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"   />


                        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"  Text="{Binding title}" 

                                               Foreground="Black"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"

                                               />
                    </StackPanel>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: @Marcelo de Aguiar I don't know the exact technical reason for that, but in the "Developers Guide to Windows 10" it's told that you have to do it this way. (Sorry that I cannot explain it properly... maybe you can ask the trainers directly)
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-RTM/Adaptive-UI/player#time=0h21m14s

Comment: I've tried different solutions, but nothing of these work. With you code it finally works. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you very much!